# Why doesn't Jenkins recognize global ANT_ARGS?

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have a centralized ANT build file that I use for generic tasks.

When I do this in shell:

```
export ANT_ARGS="-buildfile /var/lib/jenkins/my-build-file.xml"
ant some-target
```

It works fine.

In Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties, I have

`ANT_ARGS=-buildfile /var/lib/jenkins/my-build-file.xml`

and I trigger a build that invokes the same target, nothing happens. Same result with

`ANT_ARGS="-buildfile /var/lib/jenkins/my-build-file.xml"`

(These were both defined in the key-value pair section)

The only way to make the build work is by forcing the project to have the same workspace as the build file. Am I missing something? In each build that I trigger I can see that the environment variable is being set. Is there something else that I have to do?

EDIT: Just want to clarify - for the build step that invokes ANT I do not want to set anything either. I just want any project that has an "invoke ant" build step to default to that specific build file, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Try to read out the environment from inside a test build.xml to see whether and how it arrives.

Comment: `ANT_ARGS` is evaluated *after* the build verifies that there's a `build.xml` in the project workspace. Then it picks them up and starts looking for `/var/lib/jenkins/my-build-file.xml`

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: I believe that it's either a bug in Jenkins, or something that the maintainers never thought of - ANT invocations don't really work with `ANT_ARGS` that use the `-buildfile` or `-f` flags.